# Ново-коронавирусная пневмония?

Tags: словообразование, переводы

Как известно, государственный комитет по здравоохранению Китая [присвоил новому вирусу](https://lenta.ru/news/2020/02/09/ncp/) временное название ***"Novel Coronavirus Pneumonia"***.

Подскажите, как правильнее записать это в соответствии с нормами русского языка?

> **"Ново-коронавирусная пневмония"**

или

> **"Новокоронавирусная пневмония"**

Теоретически, допустимы более длинные варианты: **"Новая коронавирусная пневмония"** или **"Пневмония, вызываемая новым коронавирусом"**, но это будут скорее краткие описания болезни, а не имена собственные. Поэтому хотелось бы понять, какой из двух более коротких вариантов в большей соответствует языковым нормам. Мне кажется более правильным первый вариант (через дефис), но полной уверенности нет.

Comment: Я бы вместо этого рассмотрел вариант "неокоронавирус"  с производными словами. Плохо воспринимается добавление русского корня к иноязычным терминам - выходят очередные "морепродукты".

Comment: @Alex_ander, очень интересный вариант, на мой взгляд. Если Вам не трудно, опубликуйте его в качестве ответа, и если присутствующие на сайте медики не найдут в нем чего-либо крамольного, я бы принял его в качестве ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замечу для начала, что слитное написание слова **коронавирусный** прямо противоречит правилам русского языка. И если посмотреть академический орфографический словарь Лопатина 2012 г. издания, то в нём зафиксировано дефисное написание **коронавирус**. Однако научное сообщество медиков и биологов отказалось в этом случае следовать словарю и под его давлением в 2016 г. было принято решение о слитном написании этого слова в качестве исключения. Подробнее об этом можно почитать [здесь](http://www.ruslang.ru/doc/ortho/Beshenkova_Ivanova-2018-aspektnoje_opisanije.pdf).

Что касается "Novel Coronavirus Pneumonia", однозначно можно сказать, что дефисное написание "ново-коронавирусный" не соответствует нормам русского языка (сложные слова с первой частью *ново* пишутся слитно). По смыслу этот термин означает именно "пневмонию, вызванную новым коронавирусом", поэтому слитное написание "новокоронавирусный" мне представляется более логичным, чем вариант "новая коронавирусная пневмония". Но, судя по всему, в языке очень быстро распространяется именно такая калька и с этим снова придётся считаться.

Comment: grizzly, странно, а разве название вируса раньше было известно? Я о том, что оно присутствует в словаре Лопатина от 2012г.

Comment: @Серж Всякие атипичные пневмонии — это всё коронавирусы. Впервые такой вирус нашли лет 50 тому.

Comment: @grizzly, большое спасибо за пояснения. Жаль, что слово "новокоронавирусный" очень трудно читаемое с непривычки.

Comment: @grizzly, ну да. Но в России до этого было известно это название?

Comment: @Серж Конечно. Правда, не всем. Там по ссылке в районе стр. 122-123. Посмотрите, оно любопытно (там и не только про коронавирусы).