# Почему коронавирус?

Tags: орфография, словообразование, сложные-слова

Слово `коронавирус` образовано сочетанием слов `корона` и `вирус`. По правилам русского языка в сложных словах корни объединяются через `о` или `е`, но не через `а` или `и`. Так почему же `коронавирус`, а не `короновирус`?

Comment: Как Вы думаете, это уже обсуждалось здесь? [Действительно](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/458247/183462).

Comment: @grizzly, я поискал перед тем как спрашивать и видел тот вопрос. Там про приставку `ново-`, а я про букву `а`. Там в одном предложении упоминается про дефисное написание, но ставить дефис в сложном слове я тоже причин не вижу, а деталей никаких. Так что мой вопрос отличается от того.

Comment: Слово образовано _не_ в русском языке, оно заимствовано целиком. По транскрипции соответствует английскому варианту coronavirus.

Comment: @Qwertiy По поводу дефисного написания Вы ошибаетесь, но я согласен, что лучше дать отдельный ответ на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведу пояснение, взятое по [этой ссылке](http://www.ruslang.ru/doc/ortho/Beshenkova_Ivanova-2018-aspektnoje_opisanije.pdf).

> **корона-вирус** 2012, уз. *коронавирус*, в словарях слова нет. Узуальная норма употребления медицинского термина соответствует интернациональному латинскому термину *Coronaviridae*. Название дано по характерной форме: «из-за схожести с солнечной короной при затмении при многократном увеличении». По строению это сложное существительное из двух самостоятельных  частей,  что  определило  дефисное  написание,  рекомендованное словарем. В электронном ресурсе Академос в 2016 г. написание изменено на  слитное *коронавирус*  вслед  за  профессиональной  узуальной  нормой. Аналогичная ситуация с терминами папиллома-вирус и герпес-вирус, имеющ**их** [сохранена авторская орфография — **grizzly**] отличный от словарной кодификации узус.

На сегодняшний день в электронном ресурсе Грамота.ру написание также изменено на слитное:

> **коронавирус**, ­а [изменено, ср. РОС 2012: корона-вирус, -а (мед.)]

Comment: Думаю, что "вирус, похожий на корону" (коронообразный вирус) при _русском_ словообразовании сложением и дефисном написании оказался бы "вирусом-короной", а не "короной-вирусом" (воспринимается как "корона, одновременно являющаяся вирусом", - по схеме "диван-кровати") - семантика исходных слов (в частности их соотношение по значимости) сказывается на построении сложного.

Comment: @Alex_ander Вы из отдельных наблюдений выводите собственные излишне жёсткие правила. Никто не думает, что *кремень-парень* это кремень одновременно являющийся парнем. Или жар-птица, меч-рыба и т.п. Я не знаю никаких правил, регламентирующих, например, написание слова "рыба" до или после дефиса во всех подобных сложных названиях (их много и вариантов примерно поровну).